# How to find a QR Code position using unity and HoloLens

Tags: unity-game-engine, qr-code, hololens

I'm new to HoloLens and Unity engine Ive been trying to find the QR Code position using the program  https://github.com/yl-msft/QRTracking so that i can use it to anchor my holograms to it but I cant seem to be able to figure it out. Does anyone know a way I can do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Also see: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). This question is far too broad for SO as it is currently written. At least show your attempts in implementations and what code do you need help with.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you need to give the application webcam permission and start QR Track in the code. Then the application will automatically track OR Code. You can Refer to [QR Code tracking API reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/native/qr-code-tracking-cs-cpp#qr-code-tracking-api-reference) to use QR Track feature in Unity/C# and use **SpatialGraphNodeId** to get the coordinate. Also, please refer to [QR code tracking overview - Mixed Reality | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/advanced-concepts/qr-code-tracking-overview) for the best practices, and you can refer to this sample(https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-QRCode-Sample).

Comment: The QR Tracking is working fine it sees the code and reads the data I just cant figure out how to get its position to another object the goal is when i scan the QR code my Hologram will go to the QR code position and stay there. I'm wanting to use it as an reference point to accurately set my Holograms.

Comment: Please refer to the official sample above, [SpatialGraphNode.cs](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-QRCode-Sample/blob/main/Sample/Assets/Scripts/SpatialGraphNode.cs) and [SpatialGraphNodeTracker.cs](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-QRCode-Sample/blob/main/Sample/Assets/Scripts/SpatialGraphNodeTracker.cs) are getting the position and rotation of the QR Code. After getting the position and rotation you can instantiate the hologram yourself in Unity.

Comment: So I tried using the pose.position and the object transform.position but it still didn't work. I'm using another script that's attach to my hologram that reads a Vector3 variable from "SpatialGraphNodeTracker" I can put coordinate in the variable in the "SpatialGraphNodeTracker" script and my hologram moves so i know its reading from it. What do i get the position from?

Answer (score 1):

I was running into a similar issue. I am using Unity 2021.3.

I was following the documentation here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/advanced-concepts/qr-code-tracking-overview) along with the github repo with the sample project.

What I needed to do was change the branch to the Open XR branch
(https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-QRCode-Sample/tree/OpenXR#openxr-sample)

And when I copied the scripts and prefabs folder from the Open XR branch into my project and tested, it worked. The QR Code Prefab was following my irl QR code, when I scanned it with the HoloLens 2.

Answer (score 0):

I Was able to get it dont know if its the right way but it works. I had to add another script to the QRCode prefab cube then give the cube a tag name then reference its position using

```
GameObject[] spatial;
spatial = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("cube");
        foreach (GameObject go in spatial)
        {
            // Get script
            QRPosition qrPosition = go.GetComponent<QRPosition>();

            //If found script
            if (qrPosition != null)
            {
                position = qrPosition.positions;
            }
        }
```